# How to retrieve results in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, where-clause

I am very much new to database & trying to pull values based on regions. My table already have region (draft_region_name) column. Below is my code

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String where = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
        where = where + KEY_DRAFT_REGION_NAME + " = " + names.get(i).toString() + "";
        if (i != (names.size() - 1))
            where = where + " or ";
    }

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_DRAFT_TABLE, null, where, null, null, null, null);
```

I am getting this expection

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: AHMEDABAD (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM DraftTable WHERE draft_region_name = AHMEDABAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might've forgotten the ' for the sqlites string Try this also your sqlite should end with ';' shouldnt it?:

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
    where = where + KEY_DRAFT_REGION_NAME + " = '" + names.get(i).toString() + "'";
    if (i != (names.size() - 1))
        where = where + " or ";
}
where = where + ";"
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
where = where + KEY_DRAFT_REGION_NAME + " = " + names.get(i).toString() + "";
```

compiles, as the exception says into this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM DraftTable WHERE draft_region_name = AHMEDABAD
```

This is wrong, if you want to check for a string you have to set the search keyword into quotation marks. So this would be the correct query:

```
SELECT * FROM DraftTable WHERE draft_region_name = 'AHMEDABAD'
```

To solve it simply wrap that part your code where you assemble your `where` clause like this:

```
where = where + KEY_DRAFT_REGION_NAME + " = '" + names.get(i).toString() + "'";
```

Comment: But I can have multiple region selections which to be applied on where column with condition

Comment: yes. in this case the clause would just look like: `SELECT * FROM DraftTable WHERE draft_region_name = 'AHMEDABAD' or draft_region_name = 'SOME OTHER REGION'`